# How to animate progress view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bar-chart

I am using https://github.com/gordoneliel/LinearProgressBar. I would like to animate it.

Here is a part of code where implementing method of drawing:

```
    func drawProgressView() {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}

    let beginPoint = CGPoint(x: barPadding + trackOffset, y: frame.size.height / 2)


    // Progress Bar Track
    drawOn(
        context: context,
        lineWidth: barThickness + trackPadding,
        begin: beginPoint,
        end: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - barPadding - trackOffset, y: frame.size.height / 2),
        lineCap: .round,
        strokeColor: trackColor
    )

    // Progress bar
    let colorForBar = barColorForValue?(Float(progressValue)) ?? barColor

    drawOn(
        context: context,
        lineWidth: barThickness,
        begin: beginPoint,
        end: CGPoint(x: barPadding + trackOffset + calculatePercentage(), y: frame.size.height / 2),
        lineCap: .round,
        strokeColor: colorForBar
    )
}
```

Does it possible to add here animation?

I found how to add it to progress view: self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true). But I would like to add it to https://github.com/gordoneliel/LinearProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with layer you can try CATransaction.

You can enclose your layer redrawing in an animation block like this

```
UIView.transition(with: myView, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
myView.layer.displayIfNeeded()
})
```

Or try enclosing your drawOn in CATransaction transaction like this

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
drawOn(
    context: context,
    lineWidth: barThickness,
    begin: beginPoint,
    end: CGPoint(x: barPadding + trackOffset + calculatePercentage(), y: frame.size.height / 2),
    lineCap: .round,
    strokeColor: colorForBar
)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Hope this helps.